# send only updated field to the server

Tags: android

I have a 10 edit box in one activity to add product data and a button to submit or update data on to the server

for instance

```
product name
product category
product subcategory
product capacity
product expiry
product serial number etc.
```

now when a user click on submit button i am creating JSON of product data and sending on the server but when a user is updating existing data i just wanted to send fields those are updated. for example , if a user is updating only category and subcategory from its original value i just want to send these to fields on the server.

so how would i identify in a quick way that amongst my 10 fields which fields are updated.

```
{
   "product_name":""
   "product_category":""
   "product_subcategory":""
   "product_capacity":""
   "product_expiry":""
   "product_serial":""
}
```

Comment: Is comparing each value of the EditTexts with an onld one too slow for you?

Comment: i would set the hint of the EditText to the old value and then check the new value before sending if it equals to the hint (might not be a good idea)

Comment: Well in many other screens I have 20 fields hence I found it slow